# __call() method doesn't work correctly

Tags: php

I created class **class.minmax.php**

```
<?php
class minmax 
{
    public function __call($method, $arg)
    {
        if(!is_array($arg)) return false;
        $value = $arr[0];
        if ($method == "min")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($arg); $i++)
            {
                if($arg[$i] < $value) $value = $arg[$i];
            }
        }

        if($method == "max")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($arg); $i++)
            {
                if($arg[$i] > $value) $value = $arg[$i];
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
?>
```

and tried to use it

```
<?php
require_once("class.minmax.php");

$obj = new minmax();
echo $obj->min(43, 18, 5, 23, 10, 56, 12);
echo "<br>";
echo $obj->max(41, 69, 45, 105, 28, 91);

?>
```

but as result I got only number `105` from `max` part of the method.
It is the example from the book and I don't understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: PS. `if($method=="min"){return min($arg);}elseif($method=="max"){return max($arg);}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo, change `$value = $arr[0];` to `$value = $arg[0];`

Value `$arr[0]` does not exist within the function. So it is `null` compared with other elements of arguments array during the `min` function execution.

Comment: I make stupid mistakes due to inattention :( thanks a lot for the explanation!